# Can't check if request is ajax with $request->ajax() and Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, response

I have a problem trying to check if a request is ajax. This is my code:

Route

```
Route::post('cookies-alert', 'CookiesController@weUseCookies')->name('cookies.weuse');
```

Controller

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CookiesController extends Controller
{
    public function weUseCookies(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
          return response()->json(['status' => 'successful']);
        }else{
          return response()->json(['status' => 'error']);
        }
    }
}
```

The form (with Laravel collective, it auto create the _token)

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['cookies.weuse', ''], 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'cookie-form']) }}
    ....
    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And the js

```
  $('#cookie-form').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // .....
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data
      }).done( function (response) {
        var res = response;

        if( res.status == 'successful' ){
          console.log(res.status);
        }else{
          showError('error :(');
        }
      });
  });
```

i tried with this other way

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
```

and using jquery 3.2.1 from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

But it always return "error" from my controller.

I also tried to use **Request::ajax()** like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/requestajax-doesnt-work) but it jump the if{} and go to the else{} option from my controller.

What am i doing wrong?

**My code works on local but not on the server**

Comment: Remember to add the CSRF token to your form. `{{ csrf_field() }}` if you haven't set the meta tag, that is.

Comment: it's already added to my form

Answer (score 0):

laravel uses X-Requested-With http header to check if the incoming request is an ajax or not also you have to add @csrf field to your form :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  // add _token field for csrf protection
  data: {
    _token : ''
  },
  dataType: 'JSON',
  // add x-forwarded-with also add X-CSRF-TOKEN header for csrf protection 
  headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': ..,
  }
});
```

or you can use  [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) because laravel works better with it :

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: {
      _token: 'token',
   },
   responseType: 'json',
   headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'token,
   }
}
```

Comment: didn't work with normal $.ajax , 'i'll try axios later. 
But i notice the controller is receiving the data. The csrf_field() is inside my form. 
If i add _return response()->json($request)_ before _if($request->ajax())_ , the data is there (the csrf_field and the other fields) and got status 200.

I'll try now with axios.

Comment: Axios did't work :(  . It send the data, the controller receive it, i can see the data and use it, but the line _if($request->ajax()){...}_  is "jumped". Could Laravel be the problem? i can decide to dont use that line but now I wonder why the ->ajax() don't work.

Answer (score 0):

`Request::wantsJson()`
It's working with axios as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need set header like bellow in app.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$request->wantsJson()` works well with axios on laravel 8.